# RFC to Sign, Encrypt, Compress AS2 https message - seeking clarification on the closure of this question

Tags: stack-overflow, rfc, ietf

I am seeking clarification regarding the closure of my recent question titled "Is there RFC that specifies or mandates the sequence(order) of Signing, Encryption, Compression?"

I understand and respect Stack Overflow's guidelines and policies for asking questions, and I am committed to adhering to them. However, I would appreciate some clarification regarding the closure of my question, as I believe it may have been misinterpreted.

The closure message states: "This question is seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more." I would like to point out that my question was not seeking recommendations but rather factual information related to the existence of RFCs that specify a sequence for cryptographic operations. I find it somewhat perplexing that the phrase "and more" was included in the closure message.

I have reviewed Stack Overflow's guidelines and do not believe my question falls under the category of seeking recommendations. It was intended to seek factual information and not recommendations for specific resources.

I kindly request guidance on how I can improve my question to ensure it aligns with Stack Overflow's guidelines and policies. I believe this clarification will not only be valuable to me but also to other members of the community who may have similar questions in the future.

I appreciate your dedication to maintaining the quality and integrity of the Stack Overflow community.